# How do I change schema in fluent migrator?

Tags: c#, migration, fluent-migrator

I am trying to add column to one of our existing tables that is not on dba schema.

I tried following,

```
Alter.Table("Breakdown").AddColumn("QuoteRef").AsString(30).Nullable().ToSchema("Res");
```

but it blows up with this error message

[image]

**How do I change schema in fluent migrator?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out myself: it's not `.ToSchema("Res")` but `.InSchema("Res")`

Full code would look following:

```
Alter.Table("Breakdown").InSchema("Res").AddColumn("QuoteRef").AsString(30).Nullable();
```